# What is the maximum practical length of a mailto URL?

Tags: mailto

In my web page I make an Ajax request to a WCF service. If the service throws an error then that is passed back in the JSON. The JavaScript error handler then reveals a hidden div with a mailto URL prepopulated with my details so that team members (this is a small internal app) can send me the error including the stack trace. Here's an example resulting URL from a test run:

```
mailto:tttttttt@mmmmmmmmm.com?subject=potential%20seed%20save%20failed&body=Potential%20seed%20URL%20=%20unknown%0DResponse%20%3A%20%7B%22ExceptionDetail%22%3A%7B%22HelpLink%22%3Anull%2C%22InnerException%22%3Anull%2C%22Message%22%3A%22testing%22%2C%22StackTrace%22%3A%22%20%20%20at%20SavePotentialSeedSearches.WCFService.StorePotentialSeed(String%20url%2C%20String%20name)%20in%20C%3A%5C%5CTFS%5C%5CProjects%5C%5CSeeds%5C%5CPreliminaries%5C%5CSavePotentialSeedSearches%5C%5CWCFService.svc.cs%3Aline%2021%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20SyncInvokeStorePotentialSeed(Object%20%2C%20Object%5B%5D%20%2C%20Object%5B%5D%20)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object%20instance%2C%20Object%5B%5D%20inputs%2C%20Object%5B%5D%26%20outputs)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc%26%20rpc)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc%26%20rpc)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc%26%20rpc)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean%20isOperationContextSet)%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%22System.ArgumentException%22%7D%2C%22ExceptionType%22%3A%22System.ArgumentException%22%2C%22Message%22%3A%22testing%22%2C%22StackTrace%22%3A%22%20%20%20at%20SavePotentialSeedSearches.WCFService.StorePotentialSeed(String%20url%2C%20String%20name)%20in%20C%3A%5C%5CTFS%5C%5CProjects%5C%5CSeeds%5C%5CPreliminaries%5C%5CSavePotentialSeedSearches%5C%5CWCFService.svc.cs%3Aline%2021%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20SyncInvokeStorePotentialSeed(Object%20%2C%20Object%5B%5D%20%2C%20Object%5B%5D%20)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object%20instance%2C%20Object%5B%5D%20inputs%2C%20Object%5B%5D%26%20outputs)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc%26%20rpc)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc%26%20rpc)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc%26%20rpc)%5Cu000d%5Cu000a%20%20%20at%20System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean%20isOperationContextSet)%22%7D
```

That's 2354 characters long.

[Other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/575530) suggest that URLs above 2000 characters are a bad idea as some browsers may struggle with them. But are mailto URLs parsed in any way by the browser or are they handed immediately on to the default mail tool? If they are handed on, does anyone have data on the length of mailto URLs that various mail tool (and in particular Outlook) can handle?

Comment: check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1413986.aspx/1

Comment: That's an interesting link - the command line limits are something I'd not considered (though post XP they are given as 8191).

Comment: This question has been posed several times on StackOverflow over the years without an acceptable answer. Server-side solution may be feasible for everyone.
I posted a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74778578/3297640

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317429/mailto-max-length-of-each-internet-browsers) 
 -  yes the browser will parse the URL before sending it
 -  Safari and most email clients have no hard limit (depends on available CPU and RAM)

**2015 Web Browser Testing:**

- Safari

  - 705000000
  - 2 minutes
  - Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56
  - limited by 16GB RAM
- Firefox

  - 268435455
  - 20 seconds
  - Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
  - limited by maximum string length
- Chrome

  - 2097132
  - 1 second
  - Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
  - limited without explanation
- IE

  - 2029
  - 5 seconds
  - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko
  - limited without explanation

**2015 Email Client Testing:**

- Mozilla Thunderbird

  - 2097132 works in 1 second
  - 268435455 uses 100% CPU for 2 minutes but fails to render the body and is not usable
  - version 38.3.0
- SeaMonkey

  - 2097132 works in 5 seconds
  - 268435455 uses 100% CPU for a long time (more than 5 minutes)
  - version 2.38
- Apple Mail

  - 500000 works in 14 seconds
  - 2097132 uses 100% CPU for a long time (more than 5 minutes)
  - version 8.2
- Microsoft Outlook

  - trims to 2070 in 1 second
  - version 2013