# Large mailto links do not open in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, mailto

I have a `javascript` script where I dynamically change the `href` attribute and trigger the `click` event.

```js
var href = 'mailto:custom@outlook.com?subject=TestSubject&body=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
var element = document.getElementById('mail-link');
element.setAttribute('href', href);
element.click();
```

```html
<a href="#" id="mail-link" style="display: none;"></a>
```

However, the above script appears to do nothing in `Google Chrome`. On the other hand, it works perfectly fine on `Mozilla Firefox` where the result is that it opens the default `mail client` with the appropriate mail recipient, subject and body.

I have also noticed that if I change the `href` to a shorter value, then `Google Chrome` manages to open the `mail client`.

```js
var href = 'mailto:custom@outlook.com?subject=TestSubject&body=aaaaaaaa';
```

Is it possible to have `Google Chrome` open large `mailto` links?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: @Barmar There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Tested on Windows 10. Chrome do not open "mailto" strings longer thann 2042 characters, while Firefox does not have this limitation.

Comment: This question has been posed several times on StackOverflow over the years without an acceptable answer. Server-side solution may be feasible for everyone.
I posted a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74778578/3297640

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that body text is not intended to be the first field of the message. Its intended for short text messages, not long bodies that you're used to seeing like... long bodies of text.

Check [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) out.

Comment: It is working for `Mozilla Firefox` though

Comment: I would say look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871312/mailto-not-working-with-large-body-content

I bet FireFox just has a higher character count limit than Chrome. But I'm not the one testing it. Check your version compared to what other people are answering. I'm also curious about IE. Is it also working in Edge, since it's using Chromium... I'd bet it would fail too.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [how to get around chrome mailto maxlength limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952848/how-to-get-around-chrome-mailto-maxlength-limit). A suggestion there was to simulate a mail client to omit the issue.

Comment: answers with just a link don't work well. try including relevant code blocks and explanations for better response from the question poster.

Comment: I don't see any mention of "mail" on that page.